# Which is recommended, physical subdomain or virtual directory to separate Asp.net applications?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, iis-7.5, shared-hosting

I have a domain xyz.com on an ASP.NET shared hosting environment.

I am confused with which is to choose to separate my ASP.NET MVC 2 applications.

Whether to create a physical subdomain for each app or create a virtual directory for each app.

I also want to use the asp.net membership and role provider for all apps.

The shared hosting company structures the folder as follows:

1. **\httpdoc** is for **xyz.com**
2. **\subdomains\one** is for physical subdomain **one.xyz.com** that is a website below xyz.com website.
3. **\subdomains\two** is for physical subdomain **two.xyz.com** that is a website below xyz.com website.
4. **\httpdoc\three** is for virtual directory **xyz.com/three**.
5. **\subdomains\one\four** is for virtual directory **one.xyz.com/four**.

My questions are:

1. Which is recommended to separate applications, using physical subdomain or virtual directory?
2. Is there a side effect for each mechanism on asp.net membership & role provider?

Note:
The hosting company also provides virtual subdomain creation (virtual subdomain is often called as subdomain in subfolder). Each virtual subdomain is mapped to a folder in the \httpdoc belongs to the root domain. For example: virtual subdomain **xyz.com/five** will be mapped to a folder in **\httpdocs\five**.

EDIT 1:
I don't like virtual subdomain mechanism to create subdomain because it willl mess up the folder structure belongs to virtual directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ans 1:**

When I was thinking of registering SSL certificate, I got a statement from the registrar that I must specify the domain to register for the SSL certificate. So separating applications by creating subdomains---a subdomain for each app--- will cost more because each domain must have a SLL certificate.

**Ans 2:**

I also did many trial and errors, I think there is no side effect when a single ASP.NET membership database is shared among more than one application as long as the **applicationName** attribute in web.config is set properly.